# Dynamic URL inside Image in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to ask how to implement a dynamic URL into a Image component in react native.
The full URL of the image is:

```
https://xxx.xxx.xx/image/journal/article?img_id=3551069&t=1518189123769
```

the JSON object is :

```
{
    "announcements": [
        {
...
 "photoUrl": "/image/journal/article?img_id=3551068&t=1518189123375",
...
}
```

I use a FlatList with renderItem to iterate the array elements with list of photoUrl:

```
<List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
          <FlatList containerStyle={ styles.card }

            data={this.state.announceData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
              key = {item.articleId}
              // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
              style = {styles.card}>

              <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <View style={{width: '35%', height: '35%', position: 'relative', top: '15%'}}>
              <Image
              style= {{ height:50, width: 50 }}
              source={{uri:`https://xxx.xxx.xx${item.photoUrl}`}}
            />  
            </View>

            <View style={{width: '65%', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>              
                <Text style={styles.annoucementTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.annoucementSummary}>{item.summary}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>  
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}

          />
           </List>
```

`item.title` and `item.summary` are loading, but the image won't. Can someone propose what might be the issue? I am only testing it to an I-phone devise. Will that appear differently in Android devises?

Comment: Did you log the entire url `https://xxx.xxx.xx${item.photoUrl}` & open it in browser to verify it's a valid link?

Answer (score 1):

Try hardcoding the image path and see if it works then. Also console.log the dynamic URI to see if it's messing up somehow. Ur using the right format for string interpolation so I'm guessing it's a problem with the path itself. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours on this question but as much as I dig into this issue, I found that, it is a design decision given by react native developers. Have a look at this issue on github [Setting  source with string concatenation fails ('Requiring unknown module...')](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-137982505) . The only implementation that satisfies my needs is something like this:

```
const sampleImage= require("./assets/sample.png");
.....
....
...
export default {sampleImage}
```

And import this where do you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, it seems that when i import a local JSON file the images won't load. But when i use fetch to get the same data from a web service images will finally load! I forgot to mention that i use EXPO as a device tester..